# Unable to feed value for placeholder tensor

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have written a simple version bidirectional lstm for sentence classification. But it keeps giving me "You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'train_x'" error and it seems this come from the variable initialization step.

```
data = load_data(FLAGS.data)
model = RNNClassifier(FLAGS)
init = tf.initialize_all_variables()

with tf.Session() as sess:
    coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
    threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(sess=sess, coord=coord)
    sess.run(init)
    print("Graph initialized..")
    print()
    np.random.seed(FLAGS.random_state)
    for epoch in range(FLAGS.max_max_epoch):

        loss = sess.run(model.cost, feed_dict={model.train_x: data.train_x, model.train_y: data.train_y, 
                                        model.embedding_placeholder: data.glove_vec})
        print("Epoch {:2d}: Loss = {:.6f} = {:.5f}".format(epoch+1, loss))
    coord.request_stop()
    coord.join(threads)
```

And the `RNNClassifier` class code (in a different directory):

```
class RNNClassifier:

    def __init__(self, FLAGS):
        self.params = FLAGS
        with tf.device("/cpu:0"):
            self.train_x = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [6248, 42], name='train_x')
            self.train_y = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [6248, 3], name='train_y')
            self.embedding_placeholder = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [1193515, 100])

        with tf.variable_scope('forward_lstm'):
            lstm_fw_cell = tf.nn.rnn_cell.LSTMCell(num_units=self.params.num_hidden, use_peepholes=False, 
                                                activation=tf.nn.relu, forget_bias=0.0, 
                                                state_is_tuple=True)
        with tf.variable_scope('backward_lstm'):
            lstm_bw_cell = tf.nn.rnn_cell.LSTMCell(num_units=self.params.num_hidden, use_peepholes=False, 
                                                activation=tf.nn.relu, forget_bias=0.0, 
                                                state_is_tuple=True)

        fw_initial_state = lstm_fw_cell.zero_state(self.params.batch_size, tf.float32)
        bw_initial_state = lstm_bw_cell.zero_state(self.params.batch_size, tf.float32)
        self._initial_state = [fw_initial_state, bw_initial_state]

        with tf.device("/cpu:0"), tf.variable_scope('softmax'):
            self.W = tf.get_variable('W', [self.params.num_hidden*2, self.params.num_classes])
            self.b = tf.get_variable('b', [self.params.num_classes], initializer=tf.constant_initializer(0.0))

        batched_inputs, batched_labels = self.batch_data()
        embed_inputs = self.use_embedding(batched_inputs)


        rnn_outputs, output_state_fw, output_state_bw  = tf.nn.bidirectional_rnn(
            cell_fw=lstm_fw_cell,
            cell_bw=lstm_bw_cell,
            inputs=embed_inputs,
            initial_state_fw=fw_initial_state,
            initial_state_bw=bw_initial_state
            )


        logits = tf.matmul(rnn_outputs[-1], self.W) + self.b

        self._cost = cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits, tf.cast(batched_labels, tf.float32)))
        optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=0.05).minimize(cost)


    def batch_data(self):
        # inputs = tf.convert_to_tensor(train_x, dtype=tf.int32)
        # labels = tf.convert_to_tensor(train_y, dtype=tf.int32)
        batched_inputs, batched_labels = tf.train.batch(
            tensors=[self._train_x, self._train_y],
            batch_size=self.params.batch_size,
            dynamic_pad=True,
            enqueue_many=True,
            name='batching'
    )
    return batched_inputs, batched_labels


    def use_embedding(self, batched_inputs):
        with tf.device("/cpu:0"), tf.name_scope("input_embedding"):
            embedding = tf.get_variable("embedding", shape=[1193515, 100], trainable=False)
            embedding_init = embedding.assign(self.embedding_placeholder)
            embed_inputs = tf.split(1, self.params.seq_len, tf.nn.embedding_lookup(embedding_init, batched_inputs))
            embed_inputs = [tf.squeeze(input_, [1]) for input_ in embed_inputs]
    return embed_inputs

    @property
    def cost(self):
        return self._cost
```

**The output (including the error):**

```
I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:925] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_init.cc:102] Found device 0 with properties: 
name: GeForce GTX 750 Ti
major: 5 minor: 0 memoryClockRate (GHz) 1.0845
pciBusID 0000:01:00.0
Total memory: 2.00GiB
Free memory: 1.41GiB
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_init.cc:126] DMA: 0 
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_init.cc:136] 0:   Y 
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:839] Creating TensorFlow device (/gpu:0) -> (device: 0, name: GeForce GTX 750 Ti, pci bus id: 0000:01:00.0)
E tensorflow/core/client/tensor_c_api.cc:485] You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'train_x' with dtype int32 and shape [6248,42]
     [[Node: train_x = Placeholder[dtype=DT_INT32, shape=[6248,42], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"]()]]

Graph initialized..

W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:936] Out of range: PaddingFIFOQueue '_0_batching/padding_fifo_queue' is closed and has insufficient elements (requested 50, current size 0)
     [[Node: batching = QueueDequeueMany[_class=["loc:@batching/padding_fifo_queue"], component_types=[DT_INT32, DT_INT32], timeout_ms=-1, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](batching/padding_fifo_queue, batching/n)]]
W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:936] Out of range: PaddingFIFOQueue '_0_batching/padding_fifo_queue' is closed and has insufficient elements (requested 50, current size 0)
     [[Node: batching = QueueDequeueMany[_class=["loc:@batching/padding_fifo_queue"], component_types=[DT_INT32, DT_INT32], timeout_ms=-1, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](batching/padding_fifo_queue, batching/n)]]
E tensorflow/core/client/tensor_c_api.cc:485] PaddingFIFOQueue '_0_batching/padding_fifo_queue' is closed and has insufficient elements (requested 50, current size 0)
     [[Node: batching = QueueDequeueMany[_class=["loc:@batching/padding_fifo_queue"], component_types=[DT_INT32, DT_INT32], timeout_ms=-1, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](batching/padding_fifo_queue, batching/n)]]
     [[Node: batching/_9 = _Recv[client_terminated=false, recv_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:0", send_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0", send_device_incarnation=1, tensor_name="edge_1191_batching", tensor_type=DT_INT32, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:0"]()]]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "train_lstm.py", line 66, in <module>
    model.embedding_placeholder: data.glove_vec})
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 382, in run
    run_metadata_ptr)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 655, in _run
    feed_dict_string, options, run_metadata)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 723, in _do_run
    target_list, options, run_metadata)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 743, in _do_call
    raise type(e)(node_def, op, message)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors.OutOfRangeError: PaddingFIFOQueue '_0_batching/padding_fifo_queue' is closed and has insufficient elements (requested 50, current size 0)
     [[Node: batching = QueueDequeueMany[_class=["loc:@batching/padding_fifo_queue"], component_types=[DT_INT32, DT_INT32], timeout_ms=-1, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](batching/padding_fifo_queue, batching/n)]]
     [[Node: batching/_9 = _Recv[client_terminated=false, recv_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:0", send_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0", send_device_incarnation=1, tensor_name="edge_1191_batching", tensor_type=DT_INT32, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:0"]()]]
Caused by op u'batching', defined at:
  File "train_lstm.py", line 49, in <module>
    model = RNNClassifier(FLAGS)
  File "/home/ccrmad/Code/TDLSTM/models/rnn_classifier.py", line 34, in __init__
    batched_inputs, batched_labels = self.batch_data()
  File "/home/ccrmad/Code/TDLSTM/models/rnn_classifier.py", line 74, in batch_data
    name='batching'
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/input.py", line 595, in batch
    dequeued = queue.dequeue_many(batch_size, name=name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/data_flow_ops.py", line 435, in dequeue_many
    self._queue_ref, n=n, component_types=self._dtypes, name=name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_data_flow_ops.py", line 867, in _queue_dequeue_many
    timeout_ms=timeout_ms, name=name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py", line 703, in apply_op
    op_def=op_def)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 2310, in create_op
    original_op=self._default_original_op, op_def=op_def)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1232, in __init__
    self._traceback = _extract_stack()
```

I have tried move the `train_x` and `train_y` placeholder initialization before `init = tf.initialize_all_variables()` and feed them to RNNClassifier() as two args but it still give the same error. Why?

Comment: Please see comments of @mrry on this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34050071/tensorflow-random-shuffle-queue-is-closed-and-has-insufficient-elements. It might help.

Comment: Thanks. But I don't think it's the same issue.

Comment: Please don't add `[Resolved]` to your question title. If you have a solution, post an answer below. Otherwise, just leave the post be. Stack Overflow is not a *personal* question assistant. Questions here are meant to be helpful to *future visitors* too; people are not looking for 'resolved' markers, they are looking to see if you have the same problem and if there is an answer they can apply too.

Comment: What does `load_data` do?

Comment: Hi Eric, thanks for asking! `load_data` creates a instance which `data.train_x` is a numpy array with the shape of (6248, 42) and `data.train_y` is a numpy array with the shape of (6248, 3). Both of them have the dtype of int32 I have checked. I am really confused why they cannot be fed into the placeholders. I have tried to initialise those placeholders outside RNNClassifier class and in my main code as well (like many other examples I have seen) but still not working!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the problem is in this method, in `RNNClassifier`:

```
def batch_data(self):
    # ...
    batched_inputs, batched_labels = tf.train.batch(
        tensors=[self._train_x, self._train_y],
        batch_size=self.params.batch_size,
        dynamic_pad=True,
        enqueue_many=True,
        name='batching')
```

The two tensor arguments to [`tf.train.batch()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.10/api_docs/python/io_ops.html#batch) are `self._train_x` and `self._train_y`. In the `RNNClassifier` constructor, it seems like you create these as [`tf.placeholder()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.10/api_docs/python/io_ops.html#placeholder) tensors:

```
def __init__(self, FLAGS):
    # ...
    with tf.device("/cpu:0"):
        self.train_x = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [6248, 42], name='train_x')
        self.train_y = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [6248, 3], name='train_y')
```

...though I'm assuming that the difference between `self._train_x` and `self.train_x` is a copy-paste error, because `self._train_x` doesn't seem to be defined anywhere else.

Now, one of the surprising things about `tf.train.batch()` is that it consumes its inputs in a completely separate thread, called a "queue runner", and started when you call [`tf.train.start_queue_runners()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.10/api_docs/python/train.html#start_queue_runners). This thread calls [`Session.run()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.10/api_docs/python/client.html#Session.run) on a subgraph that depends on your placeholders, but doesn't know how to feed these placeholders, so it is this call that fails, leading to the error you are seeing.

How then should you fix it? One option would be to use a ["feeding queue runner"](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/450e9386e0cc4b81b49adb9184859411f43ef259/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/dataframe/queues/feeding_queue_runner.py), for which there is experimental support. A simpler option would be to use the [`tf.train.slice_input_producer()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.10/api_docs/python/io_ops.html#slice_input_producer) to produce slices from your input data, as follows:

```
def batch_data(self, train_x, train_y):
    input_slice, label_slice = tf.train.slice_input_producer([train_x, train_y])
    batched_inputs, batched_labels = tf.train.batch(
        tensors=[input_slice, label_slice],
        batch_size=self.params.batch_size,
        dynamic_pad=False,   # All rows are the same shape.
        enqueue_many=False,  # tf.train.slice_input_producer() produces one row at a time.
        name='batching')
    return batched_inputs, batched_labels

# ...
# Create batches from the entire training data, where `array_input` and
# `array_labels` are two NumPy arrays.
batched_inputs, batched_labels = model.batch_data(array_input, array_labels)
```

Comment: Thanks so much @mrry! I'm so glad you're back to stackoverflow this wk! I tried the simpler option (with both `dynamic_pad ` and `enqueue_many` turned `False`) and but it still gives the same `tensor_c_api.cc:485 error for feeding the placeholders for the input data..

Comment: Also with the simpler option does it mean now I cannot turn the dynamic padding option back on? Would you agree at this stage it seems the best to write and use my own batching function than `tf.train.batch` (especially if the `dynamic_pad` option is off)?

Comment: I'm not sure whether you need `dynamic_pad=True`, since in your original version the input placeholders were dense/rectangular. However, if you want to make this work with variable length sequences, then you'll probably need to use `dynamic_pad=True` and either (i) switch to an input pipeline that parses the sequences in the graph, or (ii) write your own batching function that understands feeds (e.g. via the `FeedingQueueRunner` or a similar mechanism).

Comment: Thanks @mrry! But at the moment with both `dynamic_pad` and `enqueue_many` turned `False` and rectangular inputs (I manually padded all inputs with 0s myself), the simpler option you suggested still gives the `tensor_c_api.cc:485 ` as before.

Comment: Can you share the full error text? A message about a queue being closed and having insufficient elements is usually caused by an earlier error (then printed out when the training process shuts down).

Comment: Please see the link to the error: https://gist.github.com/bluemonk482/68460e05720a18f2852e6b121733b0a6

Comment: Ah, it looks like your batch function is still depending on placeholders. Did you try calling `batch_data()` passing in the complete training data (e.g. as a NumPy array)?

Comment: Thanks. Should I not use placeholders for feeding my input data, and I am passing in complete training data (in numpy arrays) as you suspected?

Comment: If your whole data fits in memory, you can pass the entire dataset into the `batch_data()` method, and continue to use the automatic batching with `tf.train.slice_input_producer()` and `tf.train.batch()`. Placeholders are not currently compatible with `tf.train.batch()`, so if you want to use that method, you'd probably have to reimplement `tf.train.batch()` to use a `FeedingQueueRunner`. I'd probably take the first option, at least initially :).

Comment: Thanks man, you da man! Jus double-checking, what i have written below at the bottom, is the same approach as you suggested right?

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did..

I could change the way I initialised my input variables as:

```
data = load_data(FLAGS.data)
model = RNNClassifier(FLAGS, data)
init = tf.initialize_all_variables()

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init)
    coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
    threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(sess=sess, coord=coord)
    for epoch in range(FLAGS.max_max_epoch):
        sess.run(model.train_step)
        loss, acc = sess.run([model.mean_cost, model.accuracy])
        print("Epoch {:2d}: Loss = {:.6f}; Training Accuracy = {:.5f}".format(epoch+1, loss, acc))
    print()
    coord.request_stop()
    coord.join(threads)
```

And in RNNClassifier class I could replace

```
    self.train_x = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [6248, 42], name='train_x')
    self.train_y = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [6248, 3], name='train_y')
    self.embedding_placeholder = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [1193515, 100])
```

(and remove `use_embedding()`) to

```
def __init__(self, FLAGS, data):
    self._train_x = tf.convert_to_tensor(data.train_x, dtype=tf.int32)
    self._train_y = tf.convert_to_tensor(data.train_y, dtype=tf.int32)
    embedding = tf.get_variable("embedding", shape=self.embedding_shape, trainable=False)
    self.embedding_init = embedding.assign(data.glove_vec)
```

This way everything is initialised with `RNNClassifier(FLAGS, data)` before making the call to the queue runners.

I still don't know why the previous way aka using placeholders, didn't work. I have checked the dtype and data shape, they all match. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35532457/tensorflow-placeholder-variable-for-integer-or-boolean-isnt-working) seems to have a similar problem and the "answer" suggests to replace placeholder with tf.Variable. I have tried this -> input values can now be fed but obvs it doesn't work as placeholders do and only feed the initialised values..

**UPDATE:** I think the error might be caused by operating inputs batching in the RNNClassifier class, that somehow effected feeding input data into the graph (*again please correct me if you know the cause to the error, thanks!*). I have instead relocated my batching and embedding functions onto my main code before initialising my session, this way I think it makes sure all inputs are defined to the main pipeline and batching&prefetching would be handled inside the tf graph (by not using placeholders).

Here's my code:

```
def batch(x, y):
    with tf.device("/cpu:0"):
        x = tf.convert_to_tensor(x, dtype=tf.int32)
        y = tf.convert_to_tensor(y, dtype=tf.int32)
        batched_x, batched_y = tf.train.batch(
            tensors=[x, y],
            batch_size=50,
            dynamic_pad=True,
            enqueue_many=True,
            name='batching'
            )
    return (batched_x, batched_y)


def embed(df):
    with tf.device("/cpu:0"), tf.variable_scope("embed"):
        embedding = tf.get_variable("embedding", shape=df.embed_shape, trainable=False)
        embedding_init = embedding.assign(df.embed_vec)
    return embedding_init


data = load_data(FLAGS.data)
pretrained_embed = embed(data)
batched_train_x, batched_train_y = batch(data.train_x, data.train_y)
batched_test_x, batched_test_y = batch(data.train_x, data.train_y)

model = RNNClassifier(FLAGS, pretrained_embed)
logits = model.inference(batched_train_x)
test_pred = model.inference(batched_test_x, reuse=True)
loss = model.loss(logits, batched_train_y)
test_loss = model.loss(test_pred, batched_test_y)
train_op = model.training(loss[0])

init = tf.group(tf.initialize_all_variables(),
                tf.initialize_local_variables())


with tf.Session() as sess:
    t0 = time.time()
    sess.run(init)
    coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
    threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(sess=sess, coord=coord)
    np.random.seed(FLAGS.random_state)
    for epoch in range(FLAGS.max_max_epoch):
        _, output = sess.run([train_op, loss])
        loss_value, acc = output
        print("Epoch {:2d}: Loss = {:.6f}; Training Accuracy = {:.5f}".format(epoch+1, loss_value, acc))
    print()
    coord.request_stop()
    coord.join(threads)
```

And the RNNClassifier:

```
class RNNClassifier:

    def __init__(self, FLAGS, embedding_init):
        self.batch_size = FLAGS.batch_size
        self.num_hidden = FLAGS.num_hidden
        self.num_classes = FLAGS.num_classes
        self.seq_len = FLAGS.seq_len
        self.embedding_init = embedding_init

    def inference(self, batched_inputs, reuse=None):
        embed_inputs = tf.nn.embedding_lookup(self.embedding_init, tf.transpose(batched_inputs))

        with tf.variable_scope('hidden', reuse=reuse):
            with tf.variable_scope('forward_lstm'):
                lstm_fw_cell = tf.nn.rnn_cell.LSTMCell(num_units=self.num_hidden, use_peepholes=False, 
                                                    activation=tf.nn.relu, forget_bias=0.0, 
                                                    initializer=tf.random_uniform_initializer(-1.0, 1.0),
                                                    state_is_tuple=True)
                lstm_fw_cell = tf.nn.rnn_cell.DropoutWrapper(cell=lstm_fw_cell, input_keep_prob=0.7)

            with tf.variable_scope('backward_lstm'):
                lstm_bw_cell = tf.nn.rnn_cell.LSTMCell(num_units=self.num_hidden, use_peepholes=False, 
                                                    activation=tf.nn.relu, forget_bias=0.0, 
                                                    initializer=tf.random_uniform_initializer(-1.0, 1.0),
                                                    state_is_tuple=True)
                lstm_bw_cell = tf.nn.rnn_cell.DropoutWrapper(cell=lstm_bw_cell, input_keep_prob=0.7)

            fw_initial_state = lstm_fw_cell.zero_state(self.batch_size, tf.float32)
            bw_initial_state = lstm_bw_cell.zero_state(self.batch_size, tf.float32)

            rnn_outputs, output_state_fw, output_state_bw  = tf.nn.bidirectional_rnn(
                cell_fw=lstm_fw_cell,
                cell_bw=lstm_bw_cell,
                inputs=tf.unpack(embed_inputs),
                # sequence_length=self.seq_len,
                initial_state_fw=fw_initial_state,
                initial_state_bw=bw_initial_state
                )

        with tf.variable_scope('output', reuse=reuse):
            with tf.variable_scope('softmax'):
                W = tf.get_variable('W', [self.num_hidden*2, self.num_classes],
                                    initializer=tf.truncated_normal_initializer(stddev=0.1))
                b = tf.get_variable('b', [self.num_classes], initializer=tf.constant_initializer(0.1))
            logits = tf.matmul(rnn_outputs[-1], W) + b
        return logits


    def loss(self, logits, labels):
        cost = tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits, tf.cast(labels, tf.float32))
        # self.total_cost = tf.reduce_sum(self.cost)
        mean_cost = tf.reduce_mean(cost)
        correct_pred = tf.equal(tf.argmax(logits, 1), tf.argmax(labels, 1))
        accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_pred, tf.float32))
        return mean_cost, accuracy


    def training(self, cost):
        optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=0.001)
        train_op = optimizer.minimize(cost)
        return train_op
```

On a side note, I wish the Tensorflow community on stackoverflow would be more active..